# PHP find multiple curly braces in a string and replace the text inside

Tags: php, string

I have string in my database like

```
Label is {input:inputvalue} and date is {date:2013-2-2}
```

How can I extract input and inputvalue from the first brace, and date and 2013-2-3 from the second brace and so on? So that displays like

```
Label is <input name="input" value="input_value"> and date is <input name="date" value="2013-2-2">
```

Below function works only if the string has {input} or {date}

```
function Replace_brackets($rec){
    $arr = array(" <input name="input" value='input'> ",
                 " <input name="date" value='date'> ");
    $arr1 = array('{input}','{date}');
    $itemvalue=str_replace($arr1,$arr,$rec);
    return $itemvalue;
}
```

There might be more or less braces on the text such as 2 input braces and 4 date braces.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

preg_replace() with back references will work in this case http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php:

```
<?php
$s = "Label is {input:inputvalue} and date is {date:2013-2-2}";
print preg_replace( "/{([^:}]*):?([^}]*)}/", "<input name='\\1' value='\\2'>", $s );
?>
```

Or if you need to parse the name and value pairs, as @Jack pointed out, you could use the preg_replace_callback() version (you don't actually need to use htmlspecialchars() on the attribute values though. Replace htmlspecialchars() with whatever parsing function is applicable):

```
print preg_replace_callback( "/{([^:}]*):?([^}]*)}/", "generate_html", $s );

function generate_html( Array $match )
{
return "<input name='".htmlspecialchars($match[1])."'    value='".htmlspecialchars($match[2])."'>";
}
```

Comment: This will fail for input values that have > inside them, which is not explicitly forbidden by the question.

Comment: Question does not not explicitly ask for valid XML either.

Comment: thank you sam. this seems to work. what happens if the input does not have a value and if it is like {input} or {input:} ?

Comment: No worries librium. TO account for those cases you can use "/{([^:]*):?([^}]*)}/". I'll adjust answer.

Comment: Actually its "/{([^:}]*):?([^}]*)}/"

Comment: Who said anything about valid XML? Escaping is an essential part of outputting HTML.

Comment: OK Jack technically you are incorrect, Ill have to adjust answer again anyway

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex and the preg_replace_callback function

```
preg_replace_callback('~(\\{[^}]+\\})~', $callback, $subject);
```

where subject is your text and callback a function which handels the given input string and returns your replacement

for simple expressions you could use the next example, but this could be transformed into an single preg_replace(without the callback)

```
$callback = function($string) {
    preg_match('~\\{([^:]):(.*)\\}~', $string, $m);
    return "<input name=\"{$m[1]}\" value=\"{$m[2]}\">";
};
```