# Parse and replace text with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, replace

I have a string like this: "N-{id size='4'}/{date format='m-Y'}".
Now I need:

1. parse this string to get ID and DATE tag (the string can contain only one of these or both);
2. read SIZE and FORMAT value (in this case 4 and m-Y);
3. replace the string with this N-0030/112014: where 30 (this is a integer in any case) is ID value but I need of 2 zero because SIZE value is 4 and 112014 is the DATE (november 2014 in m-Y format, the format value can change).

Any idea about how can I do this?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php for the formatting. Reading/extracting is quite easy done in multiple ways..

Comment: Lot's of ideas. Regex comes to mind in many forms.

Comment: See [PHP find multiple curly braces in a string and replace the text inside](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14885871), which requires litte adaptation ([`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) namely).